# AWS CLI Versioned Download links for Windows

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want to download AWS CLI version 2.x.x.
Currently the download link only go to the latest version
how could i install a specific or an old version.
i came across this post - https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1921 , here they say that a link is available to download older versions
[https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI{64/32}-{version}.msi](https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI%7B64/32%7D-%7Bversion%7D.msi) for ex -

https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI64-1.6.9.msi

https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI32-1.7.34.msi

But this links only allow me to download a specific version of 1.x.x, the same link does not work for 2.x.x

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli

Comment: Thanks for the link, though i am looking for .msi files for windows. these site seems to have the source code.. correct me if i am wrong